# Stock Price Data - Counting Cycles in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, finance, cumulative-sum

I am working with some stock data in pandas and would like to count the number of times (or cycles) where the price is within a certain entry and exit price point.

For example, I have set:

`entry price = 136.3`

`exit price = 136.6`

My entry price is $136.3 and my exit price is $136.6. I want to begin a cycle every time the value approaches $136.3 from below $136.3, and close that cycle when the price approaches $136.6 from below $136.6.

For example, using the dataframe in the screenshot below, we will have:

- a cycle begins at Timestamp 1656682503 ($136.04) and ends at Timestamp 1656682802 ($137.15)
- a cycle begins at Timestamp 1656682803 ($136.24) and ends at Timestamp 1656682804 ($136.65)

So, the cycle only **begins** if it crosses the entry price, and only **ends** if it crosses the exit price. The fluctuations in between are ignored since they never cross the entry and exit price points.

Basically, I want to be able to build a count to count the number of cycles.  In this case, the count = 2.

I have thought of using `.sum()`, `.cumsum()` or `.groupby()`, but am honestly lost in the sauce. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a janky hack would be to write a function that sorts by timestamp, then iterates over the dataset, setting some variable 'switch' to indicate if you're in or out of a cycle, and adding 0.5 counts to another variable each time you switch, or adding 1 count per 2 switches

```py
def counter(input, entry, exit, start_in_cycle=False):
    count = 0
    if start_in_cycle==False:
        cycle = False
    elif start_in_cycle==True:
        cycle = True
    temp = input.sort_values('Timestamp', ignore_index=True)
    
    for x in temp['value']:
        if cycle == False:
            if x >= entry:
                cycle == True
            else:
                pass
        if cycle == True:
            if x <= exit:
                cycle == False
                count += 1
            else:
                pass
    return count

count = counter(input_df, 136.3, 136.6, False)
```

Give this a try. This one only counts when a cycle is exited, and would count the first exit if the timeseries starts mid-cycle. Not sure if cycles would flip on >= and <= entry and exit, but you can adjust based on need.